# How to screen-centre text when it's short, but have it aligned with another element on the left when it is long?

Tags: html, css

I have a 'header' element that has an icon on the left and a div with text in to its right.

If the text is shorter than the space to the right of the icon, then I want it centred **on the screen**, but when it is long, I want it to start to the right of the icon and fill the rest of the screen, with ellipsis.

```
| [icon]    centred           |
```

```
| [icon]Starts from the lef...|
```

Here's a jsbin to illustrate the problem:

https://jsbin.com/jaxolic/edit?html,output

I want 'START' to be just to the right of the square icon, but also 'more text' to be centred on the screen, rather than the area to the right of the icon (which is what would happen if I made #icon not position:absolute and started #text the right of it).

[EDIT] I made some changes to illustrate where I want 'more text' to be aligned - the two 'more text' text should be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works in your project purposes, but I got it to work by declaring a fixed width for your `#text` div, so that it would not try to take 100% of the container width: https://jsbin.com/votixoj/edit?html,output

Comment: The text is centred in the #text div, not on the screen. The idea is to have the text centred on the screen when it is smaller than the #text# div.

Comment: I change my example so that it hopefully better explains where I want 'more text' to be aligned.